# How to enable IOMMU on Gigabyte 990FXA-UD5 R5

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, bios

I've enabled svm and iommu in the bios, but I get "not available" from dmesg:

```
root@xen:~# dmesg |grep -i iommu
[    0.000000] Command line: placeholder root=UUID=0b6a99ef-b56b-4d71-9f63-4895d0276674 ro nouveau.blacklist=1 amd_iommu=on iommu=pt iommu=soft iommu=1 pci-stub=10de:1401,10de:0fba
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: placeholder root=UUID=0b6a99ef-b56b-4d71-9f63-4895d0276674 ro nouveau.blacklist=1 amd_iommu=on iommu=pt iommu=soft iommu=1 pci-stub=10de:1401,10de:0fba
[    5.177737] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <jroedel@suse.de>
[    5.177744] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
```

bios settings (sorry for blurriness):
[image]
[image]
system info:

```
root@xen:~# uname -a
Linux xen 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@xen:~# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"

root@xen:~# dmidecode |grep -i product
    Product Name: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Product Name: 990FXA-UD5 R5

root@xen:~# grep Processor /proc/cpuinfo |tail -1
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-8300 Eight-Core Processor

root@xen:~# grep iommu /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.blacklist=1 amd_iommu=on iommu=pt iommu=soft iommu=1 pci-stub=10de:1401,10de:0fba
```

Do I need to update the motherboard bios? It's currently at F3; if possible, I'd like to avoid it because it might brick the motherboard.